# Border between two table cells in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am rewriting existing servlet to make it look better. The tables are very complex and I thought it would look nicer if there is no border between two cells. I failed to define such CSS rule. Then I tried to change cell border color. I have failed again. There are probably some CSS rule priority issues that I cannot handle.

This is what I get on current Chrome and what I want to achieve:

[image]

Minimum reproducible code is there: http://jsbin.com/rokabaliti

```
<html>
<head><style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse;}
    table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left; vertical-align: top;
    }
    tr.all { background-color: palegreen; }
    tr.other    { background-color: beige; }
    td.chain { border: 1px solid red; }
    td.target { border-left: none; }
</style></head>
<body>
    <table class='rule'>
    <tr class="all"><td>XX</td></tr>
    <tr class="other">
        <td>YY</td>
        <td class='target'>ZZ</td></tr>
    <tr class="other">
        <td>AA</td>
        <td class='chain'>BB</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting border on `td` makes border all around on `td` and `border-collapse: collapse;` just overlap two borders it doesn't remove border, so you need to remove border of both columns.

```
.other td:first-child{
  border-right:0;
}
.other td:last-child{
  border-left:0;
}
```

**Layout 1**

---

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr.all {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

tr.other {
  background-color: beige;
}
.other td:first-child{
  border-right:0;
}
.other td:last-child{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class='rule'>
  <tr class="all">
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>YY</td>
    <td class='target'>ZZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>AA</td>
    <td class='chain'>BB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Layout 2**

---

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr.all {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

tr.other {
  background-color: beige;
}
.other td:first-child{
  border-right:0;
}
.other td:last-child{
  border-left:0;
}
```

```html
<table class='rule'>
  <tr class="all">
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>YY</td>
    <td class='target'>ZZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>AA</td>
    <td class='chain'>BB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> The border-collapse CSS property determines whether a table's borders
>   are separated or collapsed. In the separated model, adjacent cells
>   each have their own distinct borders. In the collapsed model, adjacent
>   table cells share borders.

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)**

Comment: Great work Abishek. But removing the border on left cell would be trouble. The code is dynamic and I do not know what will be there on right side when I generate the left cell.

Comment: Ohh!, You haven't mention in question that the code is dynamic,if possible can you add working snippet so we can look into it to solve issue.

Comment: Is there a chance to combine that td:first-child condition with something like not last-child? I would like to use it only when it has some sibling. (the code transforms a tree to nested tables)

Comment: @LeosLiterak You can use `:only-of-type` css selector for single child, for **[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type)**.

Comment: I have rewritten the code so I can set a style middle_cell / last_cell to the left cell.

Comment: Sounds Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try,

```
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
table, th, td { border-left: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left; vertical-align: top;
}
tr.all { background-color: palegreen; }
tr.all td { border: 1px solid black; }
tr.other    { background-color: beige; }
td.chain { border: 1px solid red; }
td.target { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Expected result 1](https://jsfiddle.net/Geethu_Jose/ukyLtL85/)

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr.all {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

tr.other {
  background-color: beige;
}

td.chain {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td.target {
}
.other>td:first-child{
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.other>td:last-child{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<table class='rule'>
  <tr class="all">
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>YY</td>
    <td class='target'>ZZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>AA</td>
    <td class='chain'>BB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Expected result 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Geethu_Jose/0nauw8ys/)

```
<table class='rule'>
  <tr class="all">
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>YY</td>
    <td class='target'>ZZ</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="other">
    <td>AA</td>
    <td class='chain'>BB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

tr.all {
  background-color: palegreen;
}

tr.other {
  background-color: beige;
}

.other>td:not(.target) {
  border: none;
}
.target{
  border-left:none;
  border-bottom:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant #1: https://jsfiddle.net/a7p2dp3o/

```
<style>
  table { border-collapse: collapse;}
  table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
  th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left; vertical-align: top;
  }
  tr.all { background-color: palegreen; }
  tr.other    { background-color: beige; }
  td.chain { border-left: 0px; }
  td.target { border-left: 0px; }
</style>

<table class="rule">
  <tbody><tr class="all"><td>XX</td></tr>
   <tr class="other">
      <td style="border-right: 0px;">YY</td>
      <td class="target">ZZ</td></tr>
   <tr class="other">
      <td style="border-right: 0px;">AA</td>
      <td class="chain">BB</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Variant #2: https://jsfiddle.net/3u2cno6f/1/

```
<style>
  table { border-collapse: collapse;}
  table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}
  th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left; vertical-align: top;
  }
  tr.all { background-color: palegreen; }
  tr.other    { background-color: beige; }
  td.chain { border-color: red; }
  td.target { border-color: red;  }
</style>

<table class="rule">
  <tbody><tr class="all"><td>XX</td></tr>
   <tr class="other">
      <td style="border-right: 0px;">YY</td>
      <td class="target">ZZ</td></tr>
   <tr class="other">
      <td style="border-right: 0px;">AA</td>
      <td class="chain">BB</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```